# FreeNAS 9.3 not booting through USB

Tags: nas

I've used Win32diskimager to install FreeNAS 9.3 onto an 8GB USB stick, and configured the BIOS of my HP Proliant Microserver to put "USB Device Boot Priority" on High.

However after inserting the USB stick and rebooting the server, it doesn't boot up completely, instead reaching a screen stating

```
This is a NAS data disk and can not boot system. System halting.
```

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you need to format the USB as NTFS rather than FAT32 or FAT16.